# Kotlin: creating an ArrayList with a specific type of a subclass

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to create an `ArrayList` containing an abstract class

```
abstract class Data {
    abstract var data: ArrayList<Entry>
    abstract class Entry(open var name: String)
}
```

I want to force that `ArrayList` to have only Subclasses of `Entry`

```
class Category : Data() {
    override var data = ArrayList<CategoryItem>()
    class CategoryItem(
        override var name: String
    ):Entry(name)
}
```

But it keeps telling me that `CategoryItem` isn't a subclass of `Entry` on the following line;

```
override var data = ArrayList<CategoryItem>()
```

As far as I know `CategoryItem` is an `Entry`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `out Entry`? Also, try to make it either `var List` or `val ArrayList` but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ArrayList` in Kotlin is *invariant* by its generic parameter. It means that `ArrayList<CategoryItem>` is NOT a subtype of `ArrayList<Entry>`, even though CategoryItem extends Entry.

If you want to override a list of `Entry` with a list of `CategoryItem`, you have at least two ways:

1. You may change mutable `ArrayList` to immutable `List` (`List` in Kotlin is covariant, so `List<CategoryItem>` is a subtype of `List<Entry>`)
2. You may declare your `data` abstract variable as `abstract var data: ArrayList<out Entry>` (it is called *use-site covariance*), but you will not be able to add elements in this list through `data` property, only to get them.

Answer (score 2):

```
abstract class Data<T:Entry>
```

this is the easaist way to force
 that ArrayList to have only Subclasses of Entry

```
abstract class Entry(open var name: String)
class CategoryItem(override var name: String) : Entry(name)

abstract class Data<T:Entry> {
    abstract var data: ArrayList<T>
}

class Category : Data<CategoryItem>() {
    override var data: ArrayList<CategoryItem>
        get() = TODO("not implemented") //To change initializer of created properties use File | Settings | File Templates.
        set(value) {}
}
```